# Max consecutive years for each customer in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I am trying to find for each customer the Max consecutive years he buys something. I tried to create a calculated field but to no avail.
I created two calculated fields

1. Consecutive: if max([Count])>0 then previous_value(0)+1+index()-index() else 0 end
2. max: window_max([Consecutive])

My data looks something like:

```
Year  |   Customer    |    Count

1996  |      a        |     2

1996  |      b        |     1

1997  |      a        |     1

1997  |      b        |     2

1998  |      b        |     1
```

So the result would be

> a:2
>
> b:3

Comment: Can you show us what you tried in a calculated field?

Comment: I wrote 2 calculated field. 1. Consecutive:  if max([Count])>0 then previous_value(0)+1+index()-index() else 0 end

Comment: and the other one called max: window_max([Consecutive])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nested table calcs.

The first calc, call it running_good_years, is a running count of consecutive years with sales.

```
If count(Sales) = 0 then 0 else previous_value(0) + 1 end
```

The second just returns the max

```
Window_max(running_good_years)
```

With table calcs, defining the partitioning and addressing is critical. Partition by Customer, Address by year

Comment: The partitioning and addressing would be done on max?

Comment: Read about partitioning table calcs in the Tableau help, but in the simple case you described, you can set both calculations to "compute using Year". If you have more dimensions in use in your visualization, you may have to edit the calculations and use the Advanced setting to choose the partitioning.